# Sql, sum de varios counts

Tags: sql, mysqli, mysql

Olá, tenho um banco com 3 tabelas importantes, estado,cidade e pedidos preciso rankear os estados do que tem mais pedidos ao q tem menos porem os pedidos estao relacionados apenas a tabela de cidade. então eu preciso fazer um count pra cada cidade e somar os counts das cidades que pertencem ao mesmo estado. porém não tenho ideia de como fazer isso. alguém pode me ajudar?

estrutura da tabela do estado:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estrutura da tabela de cidades:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

estrutura da tabela de pedidos:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Poste a estrutura das 3 tabelas, isso facilita te ajudarmos.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Considerando nomes genéricos das tabelas e campos:

```
SELECT es.nome as estado, ci.nome as cidade, COUNT(pe.id)
FROM pedidos pe
LEFT JOIN cidade ci ON ci.id = pe.cidade
LEFT JOIN estado es ON es.id = ci.estado
WHERE pe.datapedido BETWEEN '01/01/2018' AND '31/01/2018'
GROUP BY es.nome, ci.nome
```

---

Na sua estrutura:

```
SELECT es.estado, COUNT(pe.id)
FROM pedidos pe
LEFT JOIN cidades ci ON ci.id = pe.cidade_id
LEFT JOIN estado es ON es.id = ci.estado_id
GROUP BY es.estado
```

Comment: Olá obrigado pela ajuda, a saida que preciso seria estado-numero de pedidos
a sua query retorna bem diferente

Comment: @MatheusLima Alterei. Veja agora.

Comment: agora funcionou, muito obrigado pela ajuda